# how to select first child not grandchild in submenu while having a same class in jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css

i wrote this code for submenu i have submenu and grand submenu both UL have the same class i am toggling child on parent click but grandchild is also toggling with parent toggle how to prevent this issue in jquery  i used this code for toggling

```
$("#main-nav > .menu-item-has-children").on("click", function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
if ($(window).width() <= 800) {
    $(this).siblings().find(".sub-nav").slideUp();
    $(this).find(".sub-nav").slideToggle();
}
});
```

**.find(".sub-nav")** is selecting both child and grandchild and toggle both on click how to toggle only child not grandchild
please Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on your HTML structure, if your `.sub-nav` element is a direct child of your `.menu-item-has-children` element you just need to add `>` to your css selector

```
 $(this).find("> .sub-nav").slideToggle();
```

Comment: Thanks man that worked I checked this by adding class on element but when i checked the other problem was also occuring it taking element spacing then i check css and relize that i added display: block by default and it was taking that large space. Man how fool i am i wasted more than 2 hours in that bug and by the way thank you for helping....